# Pass object of type from library through intent to another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, ical4j

I have a ComponentList object from the ical4j library, and I'm loading it from a url in an initial activity and then passing it to my main activity where I'll set up the GUI with data from it.

I can't figure out how to actually pass it with an intent, however. I can convert it into a string and that works (using componentList.toString()), however I want it to still be a ComponentList object. I've read some about using a parceable, but this isn't a class I've written so I can't go into the code and have the ComponentList object implement parceable. Is there a good way to pass an object from the ical4j library, in this case ComponentList, to another activity?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [API Docs](http://build.mnode.org/projects/ical4j/apidocs/net/fortuna/ical4j/model/ComponentList.html) it implements `Serializable`. So, you should be able to send it using an `Intent`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("componentList", componentList);
startActivity(i);
```

Then, in your MainActivity's `onCreate()`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
ComponentList componentList = (ComponentList) extras.getSerializableExtra("componentList");
```

Comment: hmm, other intents work in this case but the app crashes when passing a Serializable through an intent

Comment: No error message, but the last message logged is "Late-enabling CheckJNI"

Comment: If I pass another Serializable object, such as Component, it works just fine, but ComponentList for some reason isn't.

Comment: If it crashes, there's an error log. Filter the logcat output to Error level

Comment: The only error I see says: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Chaches::initConstraints()

The crash doesn't say "unforunately, ... has stopped" but rather the simulator just exits the app.

I'm passing the intent in an onPostExecute() of an AsyncTask, I don't know if that would make a difference or not.

Comment: I solved my problem by converting the CalendarList object into a String in the AsyncTask class, passing that string as an intent, and then recreating a Calendar object from that string, using it to create a CalendarList in my MainActivity.